# save file as pdf in excel saves all sheets

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I have a button on a ribbon that will save this as a pdf. but it is saving all of the visible sheets to pdf. I only want it to save the active sheet.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    xl.Application xlApp = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application;
    ThisWorkbook wb = Globals.ThisWorkbook;
    SaveFileDialog MyFiles = new SaveFileDialog();
    MyFiles.Filter = "PDF Files|*.pdf";
    MyFiles.Title = "Save As...";
    MyFiles.DefaultExt = "*.pdf";
    MyFiles.ShowDialog();
    string path = MyFiles.FileName;
    wb.ExportAsFixedFormat(xl.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, path);
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: does the `wb` object have a `wb.WorkSheet` property..?

Comment: no, it has a worksheets

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat`.  This is consistent with how to do this in normal VBA as well.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.activesheet.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1